# Не происходит переход на страницу Python/Django

Tags: html, python, django, django-rest-framework

Стараюсь написать простое приложение используя Django REST framework но столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

***urls.py:***

```py
...
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list_view, name='index'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)$', views.post_detail_view, name='post-detail'),
]
```

Пытаюсь сделать переход от списка постов на страницу о конкретном посте, но у меня почему-то просто обновляется текущая страница.

Главная страничка, в которой ссылка на конкретный пост передается с помощью `get_absolute_url`:

```html
{% block content %}
    <h1>Post List</h1>
    {% if post_list %}
        <ul>
            {% for post in post_list %}
                <li>
                    <a href={{post.get_absolute_url}}>{{ post.title }}</a> 
                    {{post.author}}
                    ({{post.date}})
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% else %}
        <p>There are no posts in the site.</p>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

***models.py:***

```py
...
class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
    author = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='author' ,on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    summary = models.TextField(max_length=1000, help_text="Enter the text of the post")
    date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='likes', blank=True)
    unlikes = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='unlikes', blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', args=[str(self.id)])

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["date"]
```

Если вручную прописать конкретный путь в `URL`, например:
`http://127.0.0.1:8007/api/v1.0/post/1`,
то все отлично работает.

Когда просмотрел, что же возвращает `get_absolute_url`, то оказалось, что все в порядке и возвращается правильный `URL`, что запутало меня окончательно. Может быть, это какие-то особенности REST framework'a?

Код функции для обработки странички со списком всех постов:

```py
@api_view(['GET'])
def post_list_view(request, format=None):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        queryset = Post.objects.all()
        serializer = PostSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response({'post_list': serializer.data}, template_name='index.html')
```

Страничка конкретного поста

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def post_detail_view(request, pk):
    try:
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Post.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = PostSerializer(post)
        return Response({'post' : serializer.data}, template_name='SocialNetwork/post_detail.html')
```

---

Решил проблему таким образом:

```html
<li>
    <a href='http://127.0.0.1:8007/api/v1.0/post/{{post.id}}'>{{ post.title }}</a>
    {{post.author}}
    ({{post.date}})
</li>
```

Но это ведь костыль какой-то. Буду благодарен за помощь.